# Estoy intentado validar un usuario y contraseña en jsp de una base de datos y me bota este error?

Tags: jsp, mysql-workbench, jdbc

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection
>   class because of underlying exception:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database
>   URL, failed to parse the connection string near '=true&useSSL=false'.

este es el url que uso para crear la conexion:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto_jsp?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto_jsp?
>   useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&
>   serverTimezone=UTC?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

La URL termina con un interrogante seguido de la lista de parámetros, cada par "nombreParametro=valorParametro" separado por "&"

En tu caso, entre `serverTimezone=UTC` y `autoReconnect=true`, no tienes un `&` sino un `?`, que es lo que hace que la URL esté mal formada. Cambia es `?` por `&` y te debería funcionar (o al menos dar otro error no relacionado).

Comment: Gracias eso lo soluciono!!